# Compare 2 csv file using shell script and print the output in 3rd file

Tags: shell

I am learning shell script and by using it trying to build a framework for my team for their testing purpose. Thus need your help in something.

Overview: I am trying to extract the aggregated values from hive through my queries using shell script and storing the result in a separate file, let's say File1.csv.

Now I wanted to compare above csv file with another csv file File2.csv using shell script and print the result as PASS(if records are matching) or FAIL(if records are not matching) row wise into the third file, let's say output.txt

Note: First we need to sort the records into File1.csv and then compare it with File2.csv, following with store the result PASS/FAIL row wise into output.txt

Format of File1.csv

Postcode Location InnerLocation Value_% Volume_%
XYZ London  InnerLondon 6.987 2.561
ABC NY High Street 3.564 0.671
DEF Florida Miami 8.129 3.178

Quick help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far? we cant give you code from scratch

Comment: Well only the comparison section is left. I am able to extract the records from hive tables. Both the csv file with the given format is ready with me. I just want to compare both the file and print the PASS/FAIL in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two sorted text files and want to see which lines are different. There is nothing in your question which would make the problem CSV specific.

A convenient tool for this type of task would be `sdiff`.

```
sdiff -s File[12].csv
```

The `-s` option ensures that you see only different lines, but have a look at the *sdiff* man page: Maybe you want also to add one of the options dealing with white space.

If you need to go into more detail and, for example, show not just different CSV lines, but out which field in the line is different, and if there are really general CSV files, you really should use a CSV parser and not do it in shell scripts. Parsing a CSV file from a shell script really works if you know for sure that only a subset of all features allowed for CSV files are actually used.